# Проблемы с обработкой исключений в ruby

Tags: ruby, исключения

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем здесь у меня проблема ?

```
class Z<StandardError
end
class V<StandardError
end
def x(z)
  if z==12
    raise Z "z=#{z}"  
  end
  puts z
end
def si(t)
  if t==1
    raise X "x=#{t}"  
  end
  puts t
end

begin
  (90)
  si(1)
rescue Z =>  zz
  puts "Fin #{zz}"
rescue V => ss
  puts "DELO #{ss}"  
end
```

и мне интерпретатор выдает такую ошибку `'1.rb:21:in`': undefined method `ss' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Comment: ой извините вот так код точнее class Z<StandardError
end
class V<StandardError
end
def x(z)
 if z==12
 raise Z "z=#{z}"  
end
puts z
end
def si(t)
  if t==1
  raise X "x=#{t}"  
 end
 puts t
 end


begin
  x(90)
si(1)
  
rescue Z =>  zz
puts "Fin #{zz}"
rescue V => ss
puts "DELO #{ss}"  
end

Comment: Вопрос можно редактировать, если что. И отформатируйте код нормально, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле у вас тут две ошибки. Первая заключается в том, что определив два класса с именами Z и V

```
class Z < StandardError
end

class V < StandardError
end
```

Вы затем в методе si обращаетесь к классу X, который нигде не определен

```
def si(t)
  if t==1
    raise X "x=#{t}"  
  end
  puts t
end
```

В этом методе, я полагаю вместо класса X вы имели в виду класс V.

Вторая ошибка заключается в том, как вы создаете объекты исключений, которые затем передаете методу raise

```
raise Z "z=#{z}"
```

Если мы сейчас добавим круглые скобки, то выражение будет выглядеть так

```
raise(Z("z=#{z}"))
```

Т.е. с классом Z вы обращатесь как с методом, а это не верно, классы в Ruby — это объекты. Вы должны вызывать методы у объектов, в данном случае это метод new, который создаст новый объект класса

```
raise Z.new "z=#{z}"
```

Исправить эту ошибку нужно в обоих вызовах raise. После исправления этих ошибок, программа у меня заработала без сбоев.

Comment: Я вам очень благодарен за вашу помощь!!! и за вашу доброту ко мне!!! СЛАВА БОГУ!!! Что есть такие добрые люди на земле как вы!!!

Comment: У меня еще вот такая есть проблема, если срабатывает первая исключения, то второе исключения уже не работает. class Z<StandardError
end
class V<StandardError
end
def x(z)
 if z==12
  raise Z.new "z=#{z}"  
 end
 puts z
end
def si(t)
 if t==1
  raise V.new "x=#{t}"  
 end
 puts t
end

begin
 x(12)
 si(1)
rescue Z =>  zz
 puts "Fin #{zz}"
rescue V => ss
 puts "DELO #{ss}"  
end

Comment: @LiveMrak Да, это стандартное поведение исключительных ситуаций во всех языках программирования. Ситуация исключительная - все бросаем, останавливаем работу и занимаемся только ей. Другой код больше не выполняется и не возобновляет работу. Если вы хотите реализовать какую-то логику, то лучше не использовать исключительные ситуации - они для форс-мажора, не для реализации штатных возможностей. Возможно я вас не совсем правильно понял и имелось в виду что-то другое, в этом случае можно задать новый вопрос.

Comment: Чуть позже, я вам задам по другому вопрос, а так я вам искренне благодарен, за вашу доброту,  я вас еще на своем ютуб канале от благодарю, я и так редко встречаю таких добрых людей в жизни.

Comment: ОК, А какие варианты вы предложите кроме обработки исключения? чтоб можно было исправлять ошибки в 2 методах.